# How to handle bigger traffic with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Currently, I am developing an API and it is my first contact with sequelize. The API was working great, but recently the traffic has reached about 2k requests per second. Then application has started to continuously throw `SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError`. The exception is critical because if it happens once then it is happening continuously and killing the node replica. My solution, for now, is to set `{ pool: { max: 30 } }` and increase the number of node replicas. But to completely eliminate the error I need to spawn a lot of replicas, so in my opinion, it is a very bad solution. I tried to increase the parameter responsible for acquire timeout but then my API responses in a few seconds instead of a few milliseconds. I completely do not know how to approach the problem, so I want to know if it is a known issue with sequelize that is the effect of beginner mistakes. I tried to find related issues in sequelize repo, but I have not found anything that could help with my problem. Is there any set of best sequelize best practices?

If you wondering how I use sequelize:

```js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
...
let transaction: null | Transaction = null;
try {
  transaction = await sequelize.transaction();
  ...
  await transaction.commit();
} catch(e) { await transaction?.rollback(); }
```

Using other words I am just wrapping the whole endpoint logic in the transaction. `sequelize` from above is this object:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.databaseDsn, {
  pool: { max: 30 }
});
```

Comment: Are you releasing the connections when you query? how many active connections and what is the connection limit? Are many servers accessing and using the pool as well not just one server? I'd like to think you may just require raising the connection limit past defaults and observe resource usage unless many servers are involved this maxConnection per pool may need to be modified or enhanced to free inactive connections.

Comment: Did you adjust the connection limit on your db?

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I do not release connections when I query. I thought that sequelize does it automatically after all endpoint logic is handled.
Every server has its own pool and the number: `count_replicas * max_pool_size` is less than my db max connections limit.

Comment: I do not understand sequelize. So for example, if I make 5 queries inside code that is wrapped in the transaction there will be 5 connections opened? And the connections will be released when idle timeout will be reached for them?

Comment: Multiple statements in one query is a single connection, if you are querying multiple times a new connection will open till pool is filled; A connection will be re-used when the connection is released after performing query so if maximum pool was 5 connections, you can run 5 queries at the same time any other connection that comes in may error and be told to wait... :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but to clarify now. Let's assume I am querying five times inside the transaction. I am passing the transaction as a parameter to all queries. In this case, there will be 5 connections to the database that will be released after an `idle` timeout that has a default value of 10 seconds. So in this case I am wasting 5 connections for some time yes? If so, how to force sequelize to release the connection immediately after transaction commit.

Comment: @Moti I am facing the same issue. How did you handle that? I would appreciate if you can help me here.

Comment: @Nishant My application was really small so I gave up and replaced `sequelize` with `kysely`